# How to not reinstantiate a new cookie on each page load in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, session-cookies

I was having some troubles with Sessions/Cookies in CodeIgniter. After investigating with Inspect Element more I've figured out my code is creating a new cookie every single time I load a page on my website. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to prevent this from happening/only assign a user one consistent cookie per session.

My Session settings are like so:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'Writable/sessions/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = True;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 120; 
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = False;
$config['cookie_prefix'] = '';
$config['cookie_domain'] = '.myapp.com';
$config['cookie_path'] = '/';
$config['cookie_secure'] = False;
$config['cookie_httponly'] = False;
```

In addition I've given the /Writable/sessions/ folder the correct permissions and ownership. I think my configuration is fine (the cookies show up in the browser/seem to be working).

My question then, is how do I make it so that the cookie is kept consistent with the individual user on first log-in instead of creating a new cookie with missing data each time I load a page? My controller class (where I initialize the coookie) looks like this:

**BaseController.php**

```
class BaseController extends \CodeIgniter\Controller {
// Class vars set to null
    public function __construct($request, $response, $logger = null) {
        parent::__construct($request, $response, $logger);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);

        $this->db = \Config\Services::db();

        $this->RefTypes = new RefTypesModel($this);

        $this->url = new \CodeIgniter\HTTP\URI();

        // This is the problematic code
        if ($this->session == null) {
             $this->session = \Config\Services::session();
             $this->session->start();   
    }
        $this->init();
    }
}
```

Then in my other Controllers I have code that uses the session like so:

**MyController.php**

```
class MyController extends BaseController {
    public function login() {
        // Set data in cookie and then redirect to new page
        $this->session->set('userId', $userId);
        return redirect()->to('/dashboard');
}
    public function dashboard() {
        // This is where I run into a problem...
        $test = $this->session->get('userId');  //Returns null
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('$test');</script>";

}
}
```

Essentially, since PHP is a scripting language, each time I load a new page the code in BaseController.php is run which is then running the code to initialize the session again. I've tried using the database driver as well and that did not remedy the problem. Does anyone know of any workarounds to this or any way to have a "shared" instance of my session variable so that it'll be independent of my controllers? Thank you!! Any help is very much appreciated :)

EDIT: My /application/config/config.php appears to have no effect. I think this is because I'm on CI4 instead of CI3. I've been setting my Session settings explicitly right now. The code for that looks like this:

**/system/Session/Session.php**:

```
public function __construct(\SessionHandlerInterface $driver, $config) {
        $this->driver = $driver;

        $config->sessionSavePath = BASEPATH . 'Writable/sessions/';
        $config->sessionMatchIP = True;
        $config->cookieDomain = '.autoloapp.com';

        $this->sessionDriverName = $config->sessionDriver;
        $this->sessionCookieName = $config->sessionCookieName;
        $this->sessionExpiration = $config->sessionExpiration;
        $this->sessionSavePath = $config->sessionSavePath;
        $this->sessionMatchIP = $config->sessionMatchIP;
        $this->sessionTimeToUpdate = $config->sessionTimeToUpdate;
        $this->sessionRegenerateDestroy = $config->sessionRegenerateDestroy;

        $this->cookieDomain = $config->cookieDomain;
        $this->cookiePath = $config->cookiePath;
        $this->cookieSecure = $config->cookieSecure;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing CI3 when running CI 4.  have you seen the CI4 Docs? It should auto init once you've called the service.   https://bcit-ci.github.io/CodeIgniter4/libraries/sessions.html#initializing-a-session

Comment: I am on CI4 and I have it instantiating/loading as I do above. I thought that since it was auto instantiated I would be able to completely avoid this problem but either I'm not loading it correctly or the Alpha version of CI4 doesn't play nicely with sessions. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you setting session and cookie config values in `/application/Config.App.php`? If not, how and when are you providing them to the `Session` constructor?

Comment: Also, the test `if ($this->session == null) {` expects the class property `$session` to exist otherwise an exception will be thrown. How and where are you creating this property?

Comment: `BASEPATH` is the path to the system directory. Your `$sessionSavePath` value should be `ROOTPATH . 'writable/sessions/';`

Comment: @DFriend I do not have the /application/Config.App.php file. I updated the question to show the code I'm using to temporarily force certain session settings, although this obviously isn't ideal for production. I'm defining the $this->session = null; as a public class variable above the constructor. Does the location of the /writable/sessions/ matter? I thought as long as perms/ownership were correct and I passed an absolute path it would work regardless.

Comment: I'm taking a look at a new CI4 project to try and figure out the config file missing problem, it should definitely be there. I inherited this project from a dev who left before the project could be completed and he did a less than stellar job of actually setting up the framework...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this (finally) but replacing all the /application files and all of the /shared/config files with files from the default CI4 framework. I was using CI3 files (shoutout to the dev before me) and updating these config files with the correct values fixed the problem. I also deleted the code in BaseController.php that was creating the session. Thanks to @DFriend for helping me figure out the problem!